# Range and update queries

Tags: data-structures, array-algorithms

Given an array there are two types of queries :

1) Add index*(given_val) to each array element where index is the index of the element of array

2) Find the minimum over a range

Example :

```
Array : 1 3 4
Type 1 query : 5 
      New array : 6 13 19
Type 2 query : ans = 6
```

I am not able to figure out a way to do the above thing in efficient time .

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Binary Indexed Tree**.
 Time Complexity: O(q*log(n)) where q is number of queries.

Comment: Could you elaborate please .